# whether visual studio 2008 extensions available for sharepoint 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

In visual studio 2008 is have any plugines or extensions (executable file) for the sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite visual studio extension for SharePoint is [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com) which work on VS 2005/2008/2010 for SharePoint 2007/2010

But if you're going to develop for SharePoint 2010, it'll be a shame not to upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 where Microsoft finally made some SharePoint tools that work